# loop through hashes and produce new hash/array in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

Hi guys I am having trouble to find out a solution to a problem.So I have an array like bellow.

```
{
"9": [
    {
        "id": "9",
        "day": "2017-08-02",
        "voltage": "3397.1"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "day": "2017-08-01",
        "voltage": "11518.67"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "day": "2017-07-31",
        "voltage": "12835.5900000002"
    }
],
"11": [
    {
        "id": "11",
        "day": "2017-08-02",
        "voltage": "910.21"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "day": "2017-08-01",
        "voltage": "3616.43"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "day": "2017-07-31",
        "voltage": "2085.37"
    }
],
"12": [
    {
        "id": "12",
        "day": "2017-08-02",
        "voltage": "4793.96"
    },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "day": "2017-08-01",
        "voltage": "17762.2999999998"
    },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "day": "2017-07-31",
        "voltage": "18334.4000000001"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now what I want to do is to produce an array like below

```
{
   "9": [
          "day": ["2017-08-02", "2017-08-01", "2017-07-31"],
          "voltage": ["3397.1", "11518.67", "12835.5900000002"]
        ],
   "11": [
          "day": ["2017-08-02","2017-08-01", "2017-07-31"]
          "voltage": ["910.21", "3616.43", "2085.37"]
         ] 
    ...
}
```

and so on.
I have tried to iterate over the array using `.each` and `.map` method but it didn't work.I search trough existing solutions in stackoverflow but nothing helps me out.
Can some one help me with this.
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Note: both of your structures are hashes.

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also, please clarify your question: you talk about arrays, but none of the objects you show are arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define `hash` as the original object you can do it with `reduce` like so:

```
result = hash.reduce({}) do |memo, (key, vals)|
  memo[key] = {
    "day" => vals.map { |val| val[:day] },
    "voltage" => vals.map { |val| val[:voltage] }
  }
  memo
end
```

You can also do it with just `each`:

```
result = {}
hash.each do |key, vals|
  result[key] = {
    "day" => vals.map { |val| val[:day] },
    "voltage" => vals.map { |val| val[:voltage] }
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if you are writing your hash as JSON or Ruby, but I didn't have time to rewrite it to Ruby, to I just copy pasted it into a script, which made all the keys be symbols.

I believe this should be working:

```
new_hash = {}
current_hash.each do |key, value_array|
  new_hash[key] ||= {}

  value_array.each do |values|
    new_values = values.dup
    new_values.delete(:id)

    new_values.each do |attribute_name, attribute_value|
      new_hash[key][attribute_name] ||= []
      new_hash[key][attribute_name] << attribute_value
    end
  end
end
```

Which gives me this result:

```
{:"9"=>{:day=>["2017-08-02", "2017-08-01", "2017-07-31"], :voltage=>["3397.1", "11518.67", "12835.5900000002"]}, :"11"=>{:day=>["2017-08-02", "2017-08-01", "2017-07-31"], :voltage=>["910.21", "3616.43", "2085.37"]}, :"12"=>{:day=>["2017-08-02", "2017-08-01", "2017-07-31"], :voltage=>["4793.96", "17762.2999999998", "18334.4000000001"]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution from me :)

For Ruby 2.4.0:

```
hash.transform_values do |values| 
  values.each_with_object({}) do |value, memo| 
    memo[:day] ? memo[:day] << value[:day] : memo[:day] = [value[:day]]
    memo[:voltage] ? memo[:voltage] << value[:voltage] : memo[:voltage] = [value[:voltage]]
  end
end
```

And for earlier:

```
hash.map do |key, values| 
  [
    key,
    values.each_with_object({}) do |value, memo| 
      memo[:day] ? memo[:day] << value[:day] : memo[:day] = [value[:day]]
      memo[:voltage] ? memo[:voltage] << value[:voltage] : memo[:voltage] = [value[:voltage]]
    end
  ]
end.to_h
```